# Why is an iterator used instead of a for loop?

Tags: java, arrays, iterator

I'm looking at this code: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bridge-in-a-graph/

```
Iterator<Integer> i = adj[u].iterator();
while (i.hasNext())
{
    int v = i.next();  // v is current adjacent of u
    ...
```

Why didn't the author just use a for loop? Wouldn't this be the same?

```
for (int v: adj[u])
```

Comment: Please include the definition of `adj`.  Collection iterators can do certain things which enhanced for loops cannot, e.g. delete from the collection while iterating.  This must be a duplicate of some other question.

Comment: "Why didn't the author just use a for loop?" You should ask the author, we can't look inside the author's mind. Possible reasons: the code might be very old, from before the enhanded for-loop was introduced. Or the author is not familiar with Java and used whatever they knew about it. For anyone else than the author, this is an opinion-based question.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Or maybe OP isn't sure they're equivalent.

Comment: They are the same ... unless the "..." code is doing something with the iterator.

Comment: @shmosel I wasn't sure if they're equivalent. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Java, one use of `Iterator<E>` is to remove elements from a `Collection<E>` while iterating.  If you were to attempt to remove the same element from the same `Collection` while iterating over it with `for (int v : adj[u])`, then a `ConcurrentModificationException` would be thrown.

If no element is being removed, then yes, both choices of syntax would suffice.

As for why the author of that article didn't use a for-loop, you'd have to ask them.  Their code doesn't seem to be removing any elements from the `LinkedList<Integer>` within the loop, so it was most likely a subconscious choice.